# Can't understand add method of this queue

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I've found this example on a power point that describes the queue using Java.
The whole code is good until I get the Add method which adds new Node or new value to the queue, here is the add method code:

```
 public void add(String value ){
        Node node = new Node(value, null);
        if(isEmpty())
            front = rear = node;
        else {
            //I don't understand these two lines
            rear.next = node; //
            rear = node; //
        }
    }
```

I can't understand the above 2 lines `rear.next=node` and `rear =node`, whey we assign next and current to *the same object of Node?*

Here is code of Class Node:

```
 class Node {
        String value;
        Node next;

        public Node(String value, Node next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
        public Node(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you see when you drew it out on paper?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I drow it on paper 3 times, I'm sorry I can't imagine it :( that's why I posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the node to the end of the queue. Or in other words, the node after the end should be the new node:

```
rear.next = node;
```

Now that we have appended a node to the end, the last node is different, not what it was before we appended. The new last node is the node we just added:

```
rear = node;
```

Comment: So `rear=node` means that the rear moves to the end of the queue, right?